# Joining tables in Yii

Tags: php, join, yii, inner-join

I have two tables, `tbl_student` and `tbl_record`. I want to join them but I don't know how to do it in Yii. I'm using php. I found tutorials mentioning `CDbCriteria` and

```
'join'=>"INNER JOIN...."
```

I don't know what function the codes should be in and what model the codes should be placed. `tbl_student` has `stud_id` primary key and `tbl_record` has `record_id` primary key and `stud_id` as foreign key. Could someone please tell me the step by step process?

Comment: You seem to have no idea of what to do. I suggest you learn yii deeper.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use manual joins. This can be done easier with Active Record. But giving you the entire "step by step process" doesn't really benefit you as much as you think, you should learn the basics yourself and come up with specific questions instead. *If this answer is too confusing, then Alfredo is right and you should spend more time learning the framework before continuing.*

*Step 1*: Specify table relations in the respective models. If your database schema utilizes foreign keys (it absolutely *should*), then the `gii` model generator can determine these automatically, otherwise you need to declare them manually:

```
/**
 * @property Record[] $records
 */
class Student extends CActiveRecord {
  // other code...
  public function relations() {
    return array(
      // other relations
      array('records', self::HAS_MANY, 'Record', 'stud_id'),
    );
  }
}

/**
 * @property Student $student
 */
class Record extends CActiveRecord {
  // other code...
  public function relations() {
    return array(
      // other relations
      array('student', self::BELONGS_TO, 'Student', 'stud_id'),
    );
  }
}
```

*Step 2*: use Active Record and the relations in the controller action. This depends very much on what you're trying to do.

Example: load a single Student with all his/her Records. Note that I'm printing out data directly in the action - this is a bad idea and I use it here just for brevity, in a real application you will want to render a view with this data instead.

```
public function actionStudentInfo($id) {
  $student = Student::model()->with('records')->findByPk($id);
  if(!$student) {
    throw new CHttpException(404, "Student not found!");
  }
  echo "<h2>Found the requested student with details:</h2>",
    "<pre>", htmlspecialchars(print_r($student->attributes, true)), "</pre>";
  if(count($student->records)) {
    echo "<h3>Student records:</h3>", "<ul>";
    foreach($student->records as $record) {
      echo "<li><pre>", htmlspecialchars(print_r($record->attributes, true)), "</pre></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
  } else {
    echo "<p>Student has no records...</p>";
  }
}
```

The key part of this is the `->with('records')` call. It tells the Active Record system to include the Student model's `records` relation data in the query. Active Record will readl that relation and include it in the query and the returned results - the `Student`'s `Records` will be available in `$student->records` (this will be an array).

There are a lot of extra details you can include in the relation specification, for example, right now it will fetch those records in no particular order, if you want to enforce ordering, you can specify `'order' => 'field_name ASC'`.

Active Record usage is covered in more detail in the Yii documentation: [Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar), [Relational Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr).